# Change tab title of ion-nav-bar to image - ionic framework

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

Im using ionic framework to develop mobile apps. Im now concentrating in Android development. 
I want to make the nav bar of ionic framework like the picture given below.
[image]

It has a tag called  `ion-view` and attribute `title`

```
<ion-view title='TITLE'>
```

Now the navbar looks like below image

[image]

How can i add image in navbar ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can include html in the title attribute, so all you have to do is something like:

```
<ion-view title="<i class='icon ion-ios7-lightbulb-outline'></i> TITLE">
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AcKqk

Comment: It Worked. Can i use image tag in title ?

Comment: Yup! It was just more straightforward for me to use an icon in the example.

Comment: In ionic 1.3 you should use `ion-nav-title` directive (see [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavTitle/)). Otherwise the title of the window will have raw HTML.